# Check same elements in two lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, c#-2.0, listitem

I have a List and a ListItemCollection and want to check if there have the same elements.

First, I fill the ListItemCollection with Text and Value. (After a SQL Select)

```
ListItemCollection tempListName = new ListItemCollection();
ListItem temp_ListItem;

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
       while (reader.Read())
       {
          temp_ListItem = new ListItem(reader[1].ToString(), reader[0].ToString());
          tempListName.Add(temp_ListItem);
       }
    }
```

and I have the List

```
List<string> tempList = new List<string>(ProfileArray);
```

with some values like {"1","4","5","7"}

now, I want to check, if the tempList have maybe some elements with the same value in tempListName and read the text from the value adn write it in a new list.

Note: Im using asp.net 2.0.

Comment: Do you have this `tempList` available when loading data into the `ListItemCollection`?

Comment: yes, it is all in the same method. dont want to post the complete method...

Comment: I cant use Linq, cause of the 2.0 framework.

Comment: sorry, my fault. did not know which .net version was at asp.net 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real simple solution that you can customize and optimize as per your needs.

```
List<string> names = new List<string>(); // This will hold text for matched items found
foreach (ListItem item in tempListName)
{
    foreach (string value in tempList)
    {
        if (value == item.Value)
        {
            names.Add(item.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works, but I think its is not good for the memory. Thank you!

Comment: @ManuelFischer As I stated you need to optimize it as per your use case. For example, right now it is near to O(n2); if you remove the value from tempList inside the inner loop when the item is matchd, further iterations will be reduced.

Answer (score 4):

[`List.FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fh1w7y8z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) was already available   in C# 2.0:

```
List<string> newList = tempList.FindAll(s => tempListName.FindByText(s) != null);
```

[`ListItemCollection.FindByText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbytext.aspx):

> Use the FindByText method to search the collection for a ListItem with
>   a Text property that equals text specified by the text parameter. This
>   method performs a case-sensitive and culture-insensitive comparison.
>   This method does not do partial searches or wildcard searches. If an
>   item is not found in the collection using this criteria, **null is
>   returned**.

Comment: I tried it, but it throws 3 erroes.
Error 9 invalid command >.
Error 10 ) expected.
Error 11 ; expected.

I think, s => is not working.

Answer (score 0):

So, for a real simple example, consider something like this:

```
List<string> tempTextList = new List<string>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    string val = reader[0].ToString(),
        text = reader[1].ToString();

    if (tempList.Contains(val)) { tempTextList.Add(text); }

    temp_ListItem = new ListItem(text, val);
    tempListName.Add(temp_ListItem);
}
```

Now, just having a listing of the text values doesn't do you much good, so let's improve that a little:

```
Dictionary<string, string> tempTextList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    string val = reader[0].ToString(),
        text = reader[1].ToString();

    if (tempList.Contains(val)) { tempTextList.Add(val, text); }

    temp_ListItem = new ListItem(text, val);
    tempListName.Add(temp_ListItem);
}
```

Now you can actually find the text for a specific value from the dictionary. You might even want to declare that `Dictionary<string, string>` in a higher scope and use it elsewhere. If you were to declare it at a higher scope, you'd just change one line, this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> tempTextList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

to this:

```
tempTextList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var resultList = new List<string>();
        foreach (string listItem in tempList)
            foreach (ListItem listNameItem in tempListName)
                if (listNameItem.Value.Equals(listItem))
                    resultList.Add(listNameItem.Text);
```